# What other emulators work with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have about had it with Eclipses emulator and its bugs/lack of power.

are there any emulators you guys suggest?

I would prefer one I could install on my PC (In a VM or on a USB stick or something) on a separate partition or whatever needs to happen.

I would prefer one that can go online but really, anything but the default I would love.

I have also tried Blue Stacks, I don't really like it.

Comment: Genymotion eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked a lot of questions, and the answer is complicated based on your specific needs.

If you have an Intel Processor (and don't play to use Google services - like location, or GCM) - the HAXM emulator is great.  It is included in the standard SDK, and works well.

There are many ways to optimize the standard emulator, so don't necessarily dismiss it.  There are a variety of ways to configure it to be more powerful.  It may not be perfect, but it works well (if you take the time to learn how to set it up optimally - most people do not).

Another alternative is Genymotion.  This is a 3rd party, and they basically have optimized the emulator experience already, and done a lot of the dirty work for you.  They also provide some of their own emulator management tools.  I used it in early days, and found it buggy, but it is being constantly updated (recently updated, to remove the ability to use Play Services, like GMail, or Play Market - I am sure Google forced this, and is a bummer).  Overall, this is a good tool, and probably a good suggestion.

Lastly, a lot of people use a physical device for development, which is generally pretty good.  It supports Google, and Play services already, performs like a real device, and interfaces with the SDK tools well.

Every Android emulator will be able to connect to the Internet, so that is not a differentiator.

You can do what you want, but the documentations specifically states that you shouldn't try to run an emulator from Network attached storage (I would guess USB would not work well).  You could create a separate partition, won't make a difference for any of these choices.

Bottom line, there are lots of options, learn a bit about the standard tools before abandoning them.  They work well (if you learn how to use them properly).

Comment: Wow, Genymotion is freakin amazing.  I can't believe I have been using the eclipse emulator for so long, this thing is lightening fast.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider moving over to android studio. It's based around the intellij Idea IDE and has a fantastic emulator compared to eclipse. It emulates in real time in the xml editor which saves a lot of time running the program.

Alternatively you could buy a cheap android phone over ebay or something similar and use it as an emulator. This is what I tend to do as I prefer to see it working on a multitude of devices.

Comment: The Android Studio layout viewer is not really an emulator.  Will work for laying out UI, but not for basically any more complicated testing.  Also, Android Studio has some significant limitations (including being basically Alpha right now).  I wouldn't suggest using it (now).